# How To Do GetAsyncKeyState (Keys.Variable < 0)

Tags: c#

Hay, i'm trying to make a listbox with different letters and essentially if you select A it will send something like

```cs
string keyb;
    keyb = "Keys." + cmbobox.SelectedItem;
    if (GetAsyncKeyState(keyb) < 0)
    {
       //code here
    }
```

Instead of doing an if or switch (which i can't do a switch as this if condition checks for multiple things), any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide your code in the form of a [mre] (which would include the import statement for `GetAsynchKeyState`). A few lines out of context do not provide any information. Also, GetAsynchKeyState does not take a string as its argument, so the code you've written should not compile, much less execute. Did you read the documentation for that function?

Comment: i don't know what you're possibly going to do with this but sure [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(Keys vKey); i also explained everything i need to there's no context needed i'm not solving a maths problem i'm trying to do something with getasynckeystate which shouldn't need any context, if i was to ask "how do i parse a string into an integer" you wouldn't say "you need to context, you have provided minimal information".

Comment: edit: i just read your edit, and yes i'm aware this is invalid code which is why i'm asking the question, the docs was for c++ and didn't even have what i needed for c++

Comment: Yes. `Keys.vKey` is not a string, and you're trying to pass it a string. That's exactly the point I was making, which is why it was relevant to ask for the declaration to be in your question. You can read the declaration yourself - it doesn't say `string`, it says `Keys.vKey`, which is not the same as a string containing `"Keys.A"`. `Keys.vKey` is an integer.

Comment: So, what you meant to say was "I want to use the selection made in a `ListBox` as the key to test using `GetAsyncKeyState` - how do I translate my `ListBox` selection into a `vKey`?" Then the answer would be `Enum.Parse(typeof(Keys), cmbobox.SelectedItem)`

Comment: how would i use the enum.parse? would i turn it into a variable?

Answer (score 0):

`GetAsyncKeyState` get an enum. You can convert list box items to the enum. Take a look at [Keys Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keys?view=net-5.0)

Then, you can use something like this:

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(Keys ArrowKeys);
```

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Keys key = (Keys)Enum.Parse(typeof(Keys), listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
    var x = GetAsyncKeyState(key);
    MessageBox.Show(x.ToString());
}
```

[image: Output]

I hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for this, i'm going to try use this in an if statement (the code was valid)

Comment: Please do not add a comment on your question or on an answer to say "Thank you". Comments are meant for requesting clarification, leaving constructive criticism, or adding relevant but minor additional information – not for socializing. If you want to say "thank you," vote on or accept that person's answer.
[What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)